# How to get coordinates on a circle

Tags: coordinates, geometry

I need to draw a circle by drawing line from a point to each degree of circle. 
Drawing a line requires start x,y and stop x,y. So Stop x,y are the coordinates on the circle.
So how to get all coordinates on the circle.

Answer (score 4):

Usually you compute a circle like

```
x = radius*cos(angle);
y = radius*sin(angle);
```

and let angle vary from 0 to 2*pi

If the circle has a center other than 0,0 then you use

```
x = cx+radius*cos(angle);
y = cy+radius*sin(angle);
```

with (cx,cy) the center coordintes.

Drawing a circle depends on your toolkit. Most graphic toolkits provide this out of the box. You just need to lookup their API.

Comment: done..i was not converting degree into radians. after using radian it works.. nyways thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use DrawEllipse if you want to draw a circle using GDI+